# how to multiply over all rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hello Guys i wannt to multiply over all rows

```
df_innerfinal['Value'] = df_innerfinal['MENGE'] * df_innerfinal['PERIODE4']

df_innerfinal['EXCHANGE_RT']  = df['EXCHANGE_RT']

df_innerfinal['ValueUSD'] = df_innerfinal['Value']*df['EXCHANGE_RT']
```

```
    MNR         EAN  PERIODE4      MENGE          0    1    2    3    4    5         6    7    8    9   10   11   12         Value  EXCHANGE_RT    ValueUSD
0  03953  0000337672     695.0   0.833333   0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.833333  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    579.166667       1.1677  676.292917
1  04903  0000337642     550.0  64.061111  64.061111  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  35233.611111          Na
```

some tips??

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you explain in more detail your multiplication procedure, preferably with an example. It's not clear, with what you want to multiply all rows?

Comment: I would like to multiply df['value'] by an exchange rate over all rows, this result should be shown in df['value'USD]

Comment: Is this no giving you what you want? `df_innerfinal['ValueUSD'] = df_innerfinal['Value']*df['EXCHANGE_RT']`

Comment: no its multiply only the first row

Comment: Still not clear, do you have an exchange rate for the 2nd row?

Comment: df['EXCHANGE_RT'] = Exchange rate

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry, you have one exchange rate in the first row and you want to use that for all the rows, did I get that right?

Comment: yes thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
exchange_rate = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[0]['EXCHANGE_RT'])
df['ValueUSD'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value']).multiply(exchange_rate)
print(df)

    MNR     EAN  PERIODE4      MENGE          0    1    2    3    4    5         6    7    8    9   10   11   12         Value EXCHANGE_RT      ValueUSD
0  3953  337672     695.0   0.833333   0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.833333  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0    579.166667      1.1677    676.292917
1  4903  337642     550.0  64.061111  64.061111  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  35233.611111          Na  41142.287694
```

Comment: ```df_innerfinal['ValueUSD'] = df_innerfinal['Value'].apply(lambda x: x * df['EXCHANGE_RT'])```

Comment: this works for me thanks a lot